# React webkit controlled-component textarea loses focus on keystroke render

Tags: reactjs, webkit, focus, textarea, render

I'm writing a React non-native webapp with client-side rendering using the Antd Mobile component library.

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"react-redux-router": "0.0.14",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"antd": "^4.4.0",
"antd-mobile": "^2.3.3",
```

I have a small form with 2 textareas as controlled components.  When user edits text on a desktop browser (safari, firefox, chrome, etc.) it works fine without losing focus.  But on webkit, the fields lose focus during model update render(). I am using static string keys and have implemented the ref hooks to reset focus and cursor position. After each keystroke the virtual keyboard disappears and the cursor is removed from the textarea. The module is written as a "pure" functional component (rather than class).

Any ideas why webkit would be having this problem?

Here is a portion of the code that has the pieces of interest:

```
   const useFocus = () => {
      const htmlElRef = useRef(null);
      const setFocus = () => {
         htmlElRef.current && htmlElRef.current.focus();
      };
      return [htmlElRef, setFocus];
   };

   const [focusRef, setFocusRef] = useFocus();

[snip]
              key="myfieldkey"
               name="myfield"
               title="MyLabel:"
               ref={focusRef}
               onChange={(value) => {
                  let cursorStart =
                     focusRef.current.textareaRef.selectionStart;
                  onFieldChange(value /* update model */ );
                  /* timeout gives reducer time to update model */
                  setTimeout(() => {
                     setFocusRef();
                     focusRef.current.textareaRef.setSelectionRange(
                        cursorStart,
                        cursorStart
                     );
                  }, 40);
               }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a work-around, but would really appreciate any *real* answers if you find that you have a real answer.  It's fairly complicated, but seems to work on all platforms:

1. Create a local state variable for each textarea, used to store the current cursor position.  Ex.

```
const [nameFieldCursorPos, setNameFieldCursorPos] = useState(undefined);
```

2. Modify my `useFocus()` function as follows to include setting the cursor position from an input parameter.  Ex.

```
    const useFocus = () => {
        const htmlElRef = useRef(null);
        const setFocus = (cursorPos) => {
           htmlElRef.current && htmlElRef.current.focus();
           if (cursorPos) {
              htmlElRef.current.textareaRef.setSelectionRange(
                 cursorPos,
                 cursorPos
              );
           }
        };
        return [htmlElRef, setFocus];
     };
```

3. For each textarea field, create more state to get/set the focus. Ex.

```
    const [nameFocusRef, setNameFocusRef] = useFocus();
```

4. For each textarea field, create a `useLayoutEffects()` handler to reset the focus/cursor position after a render.  Ex:

```
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
       if (nameFieldCursorPos) {
          setNameFocusRef(nameFieldCursorPos);
       }
    }, [nameFieldCursorPos, setNameFocusRef]);
```

5. For each textarea field, in your on change handler, set any other cursor position to `undefined`, save off your own cursor position and set focus, then call your real change handler to update your value state (like in redux or wherever):

```
    onChange={(value) => {
       // wipe any other field's saved cursor pos
       setSummaryFieldCursorPos(undefined);
       setTextFieldCursorPos(undefined);
       setCategoryFieldCursorPos(undefined);    

       // save off my fields cursor pos / focus
       setNameFieldCursorPos(
            nameFocusRef.current.textareaRef.selectionStart
       );    

       // update value state
       onNameChange(value);
    }}
```